# "No active security context" error even with the setTimeout trick?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I have this code that is supposed to pull a thumbnail image from a remote server and return it to be displayed in Flex.  Unfortunately my code is throwing "No active security context" errors.

After searching I saw a trick with setTimeout that is supposed to fix this, but it isn't working for me.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is the Code in Flex 4.0 (Note: File is a custom class)

```
public function getThumbnail(file:File, callBack:Function):void
{
  // only for image files
  if (file.mimeType.indexOf("image") > -1) {
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    // create request
    var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    urlVars.id = file.id;
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(THUMBNAIL_URL);
    req.data = urlVars;
    setTimeout(
      function():void {
        loader.load(req);
      }, 1);
    // set load handler
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,
      function(event:Event):void
      {
        var thumbnail:Image = new Image();
        thumbnail.source = event.currentTarget.content;
        callBack(thumbnail);
      });
    }
}
```

Update I placed this in my application.mxml

```
Security.allowDomain("*");
Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://localhost:8080/crossdomain.xml");
```

And I modified the code in my action script file to

```
public function getThumbnail(file:File, callBack:Function):void
{
  // only for image files
  if (file.mimeType.indexOf("image") > -1) {
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    // create request
    var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    urlVars.id = file.id;
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(THUMBNAIL_URL);
    req.data = urlVars;
    var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(true);
    loader.load(req);
    // set load handler
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,
      function(event:Event):void
      {
        var thumbnail:Image = new Image();
        thumbnail.source = event.currentTarget.content;
        callBack(thumbnail);
      });
    }
}
```

I had to modify my server.xml on my J2EE backend to get the crossdomain.xml to show up at the root.

My crossdomain.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">

<cross-domain-policy>

    <!--This domain can accept the SOAPAction header from a SWF file from www.example.com -->

    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all" />

    <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false" />

    <allow-http-request-headers-from
        domain="*" headers="SOAPAction" />

</cross-domain-policy>
```

I still get the "No active security context" error in Firefox with the debug version of Flash Player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find the link anymore, but there was a bug with version 10.2 of Flash with debugging.  I recently upgraded to version 10.3 with the debugger and I no longer get this error.

Comment: Worked for me - always these obscure error messages when doing Flex, grrrrh!

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly (Security policies are a bit of a quagmire in Flash), The Loader class does not check the CrossDomain policy file when loading images.  You can instruct it to do so by passing your own [LoaderContext](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html) instance to `loader.load()`, for example:

```
loader.load(urlRequest, new LoaderContext(true));
```

I don't think you need to use `setTimeout` in your code; I've not heard of this practice and I'm not sure what it would achieve (other than delaying the load call by 1 ms :)

Comment: I saw this somewhere and I added it to my code but it didn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It may be as simple as loading the **cross domain policy** from the website you're pulling thumbnails from.

```
Security.allowDomain("*");
Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://domain.com/crossdomain.xml");
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this too but it tells me "Error: Ignoring policy file at http://localhost:8080/springMVCServlet/crossdomain.xml due to meta-policy 'master-only'."

Comment: Odd, give it a try on an actual domain (not localhost) as see if that works.

Comment: Ok, so I finally fixed the issues with the crossdomain.xml.  I had to change the configuration of server.xml so that my app would show up at localhost:8080/ so that crossdomain.xml will appear at the root.  Unfortunately I still have the same "No active sercurity context" error.